# dplyr count subgroups after group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

This is doing my head in. This is minimal example code from a project I am working on that seemed to be working fine this morning (with length(value)) and is not now (I've tried quitting and restarting Rstudio to no avail). Nothing else seems to have changed that would explain why this is not doing what it was. I want to group_by clinic and then count the number of observations from each clinic (as well as their min and max values). So numobs should show 3,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4.

```
set.seed(12546)
df <- data.frame(clinic = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 6), rep("C", 4)), 
             value = c(rnorm(3), rnorm(6), rnorm(4)))
df %>% 
  group_by(clinic) %>% 
  mutate(numobs=length(value), minv = min(value), maxv = max(value))

# A tibble: 13 x 5
# Groups:   clinic [3]
   clinic  value numobs  minv  maxv
   <fct>   <dbl>  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A      -0.786     13 -1.06  1.66
 2 A       1.66      13 -1.06  1.66
 3 A      -0.104     13 -1.06  1.66
 4 B       0.334     13 -1.06  1.66
 5 B       1.02      13 -1.06  1.66
 6 B      -0.642     13 -1.06  1.66
 7 B      -0.161     13 -1.06  1.66
 8 B      -1.06      13 -1.06  1.66
 9 B       0.989     13 -1.06  1.66
10 C       1.18      13 -1.06  1.66
11 C       1.10      13 -1.06  1.66
12 C      -0.980     13 -1.06  1.66
13 C       0.753     13 -1.06  1.66
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Try changing `length(value)` with `n()`

Comment: I've tried that - maybe there's something wrong with my installation. Thought it was odd.

Comment: Very weird - I detached dplyr and then reloaded it and now it's giving me the correct output.

Comment: ahh - Should have paid more attention:
    You have loaded plyr after dplyr - this is likely to cause problems.
    If you need functions from both plyr and dplyr, please load plyr first,     then dplyr:
library(plyr); library(dplyr)

Comment: In these cases try running `conflicts()`

Comment: Also make sure you use `ungroup` at the end and note you can use `n()` instead of `length(value)`.